# contextConfigLocation value for java class and xml

Tags: java, spring

I am developing an application which has two (Spring)application context configuration,one by `Java class` and other from `xml` file(`commonApplicationContext`.`xml`).

Java Class configuration -->

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:apis.application.properties")
/*
 * The component scan can be used to add packages and exclusions to the default
 * package
 */
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.surfnet.oaaas.resource", "org.surfnet.oaaas.service"})
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-repositories.xml")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfiguration {

}
```

XML configuration(commonApplicationContext.xml) -->

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.common.dao.*,org.surfnet.*">
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="org\.surfnet\.*"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!--tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="defaultTransactionManager"/-->

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="common"/>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.common.dao.entity"/>
        <!--property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/-->
    </bean>

    <!--<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
    </bean>-->

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

**Now i want to know is there any way to load these two configuration in web.xml? i have tried below,but not working**

web.xml entry -->

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
  </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.surfnet.oaaas.config.SpringConfiguration
            classpath:commonApplicationContext.xml
        </param-value>

    </context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to load the annotation config context, as it imports the XML context